# Finding $g(x)$ if $f(x) = 2x + 1$ and $g(f(x)) = 4x^2 + 4x + 3$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

I got this question for my homework in Integrated Math 3+ (IB system).

> If $f(x) = 2x + 1$ and $g(f(x)) = 4x^2 + 4x + 3$, find $g(x)$?

I understand how this works, whereas $f(x)$ is being inputted into $g(x)$. I can also solve this by simply looking at it and doing it in my head: the answer is

> $x^2 + 2$

However, what would be the complete equation and solving method used to find this answer? I am eager to know because I assume a much more difficult question will appear on the test, so I need to know how to properly solve it if i can't do it in my head.

Comment: Hint: You have $g(2x+1) = 4x^2+4x+3.$ Let $y = 2x+1.$ Then $x = \frac{(y-1)}2$

Comment: $a(2x+1)^2+b(2x+1)+c=4x^2+4x+3\Rightarrow 4a=4\Rightarrow a=1$ and $4a+2b=4\Rightarrow b=0$ and $a+b+c=3\Rightarrow c=2$

Comment: Possible duplicate of [If $f(x)=2x+1$ and $g(f(x))= 4x^2 +4x+3$, find $g(x)$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2450041/if-fx-2x1-and-gfx-4x2-4x3-find-gx)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a systematic approach: note that we can compute the inverse $f^{-1}$ of the function $f(x)$ given.  If we plug $f^{-1}(x)$ into $g(f(x))$, we have
$$
g(f([f^{-1}(x)]) = g([f(f^{-1}(x))]) = g(x)
$$
In this case, $f(x) = 2x+1$.  Solving $y = 2x+1$ for $x$ yields $x = f^{-1}(y) = (y-1)/2$. So, $f^{-1}(x) = (x-1)/2$.

We now compute
$$
g(f(f^{-1}(x))) = 4[(x - 1)/2]^2 + 4[(x-1)/2] + 3 = \cdots = x^2 + 2
$$

Comment: Summary: $$(g\circ f)(x)=4x^2+4x+3$$ $$g^{-1}((g\circ f)(x))=g^{-1}(4x^2+4x+3)$$ $$(g^{-1}\circ g\circ f)(x)=g^{-1}(4x^2+4x+3)$$ $$f(x)=g^{-1}(4x^2+4x+3)$$ $$2x+1=g^{-1}(4x^2+4x+3)$$ $$g(2x+1)=4x^2+4x+3$$

Comment: How do you do to find out $f^{-1}$ when the degree of $f$ is greater than 2?

Comment: @Piquito It's not always possible to find a neat formula, assuming $f^{-1}$ even exists.

Comment: Every one knows what you say. I suggest editing  of your "if we know $f(x)$, then we can find  $f^{-1}(x)$". Regards.